# new to Java - implementation of Java callbacks

Tags: java

I am a new to Java so this question might seem basic, please bear with me - I have been going through this [Oracle tutorial on Java callbacks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/idl/jidlExample3.html)
It states that you need to write server code called:  Server.java then you need to write the MessageServerImpl.java , then you need to also write the client code, called Client.java.

My question is how is all this implemented ? Do we create 3 seperate Java programs in Eclipse and place the server exe on the server, and place the client exe on the workstation pc, and expect them to just talk to each other ? Or do we just cut and paste the Server.java file on the server... then that will talk to Client.java file on the workstation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is two separate programs. The first, the server, comprises 3 classes:

1. Server
2. MessageServerImpl
3. ReadThread

These would live in one project.

The second program is the client and it comprises 2 classes:

1. Client
2. ListenerImpl

These would live in a different project.

First you would build and run the server project. Then in the Client class replace the string `<MyHost>` with the host name of the computer running the server. Then build and run the client project.

The way they communicate is that MessageServerImpl extends a class called MessageServerPOA which the Server class uses to listen for connections.Client has the host name of the server, so it knows where to contact the server. The client contacts the server and registers a listener with it. The server then uses that listener reference to contact the client.

Comment: good info, so I take it we are talking about 2 exe, one for server and one for client... is that right ?   If we just replace the <MyHost> with the host name, how will the server exe know which exe to talk to ?

Comment: I edited to explain it but basically the client registers a listener with the server. The server uses that listener to contact the client.

Answer (score 0):

You could have both programs running on the same pc. However, this question (and the tutorial you are following) is much more related with Corba, than with Java and Android. May be you are reading the wrong tutorial?

Comment: how does 1 java exe know to talk to another java exe  ?

Comment: You could use RMI, it's much simpler than CORBA. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136424.html